# MMC help topics Issues

Tags: mmc3

Thanks for your time here first, now ,I have a deadly issue in my current MMC project.
when i add my snapin in MMC ,and click MMC help topics menu in the help menu, I found that it always run my snapin class construction when i debug my project.it is not expection for me, and it is a deadly seriously problem ,why the construct function always run again when click the help topics ?

Any experts can point me out of this issue and give me a good advice!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's to late for the answer, but few days ago I had the same issue.
I'm using c#. Just created static boolean variable isRunning = false. And little constructor modifications:

```
public class MMCcls
{
    private static bool isRunning = false;

    public MMCcls()
    {
      if(!isRunning)
      {
         //constructor
      }

      isRunning = true;
    }
}
```